# Show that $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggl({|\tan(n^3x)|\over{n^3}}\biggl)^{1\over2}$ converges a.e

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, indefinite-integrals

Show that the sum:

$\displaystyle S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\biggl({|\tan(n^3x)|\over{n^3}}\biggl)^{\!1/2}$

converges almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$.

My thoughts:

We define $\displaystyle f_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\biggl({|\tan(n^3x)|\over{n^3}}\biggl)^{\!\!1/2}$.

Now, because then $f_N$ are all continuous except in a countable amount of discontinuities points, specifically, $\{{{\pi}\over{2n^3}}+{{\pi k}\over{n^3}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$, then $f_N$ are integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Moreover, $f_N$ are non-negative, and increasing and their limit is $S(x)$.

Then, by the monotone convergence theorem, we get:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}S(x)dx=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_N(x)=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\biggl({|\tan(n^3x)|\over{n^3}}\biggl)^{1\over2}.$$

So, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}S(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n^{-{3\over2}}}\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{|\tan{(n^3x)}|}dx$.

Now, is it sufficient to show that the indefinite integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{|\tan{(n^3x)}|}dx$ converges, right?

If so, how can I do that?

Please help!

Comment: The integral over all of $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite. You need to restrict to bounded intervals.

Comment: I see,  do we need to change the question? i.e. to ask if the sum converges a.e in a specific interval?

Or there is no problem with the question and I need to show that on every bounded interval, the last integral converges. and that I can say that because the intergral is bounded in every interval, then it is integrable on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Since the series converges a.e. on an arbitrary bounded interval, it converges a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$ (because $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of bounded intervals). Only the proof attempt needs to be modified. By periodicity, it suffices to estimate $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\lvert \tan (n^3x)\rvert}\,dx\,.$$

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: The statement "Now, because then $f_N$ are all continuous except in a countable amount of discontinuities points, specifically, $\{π/2n^3+π/kn^3\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$, then $f_N$ are integrable on $\mathbb R$" is wrong. Think of $1/x$, It is only discontinuous at $0$.